# access session or Yii in config file

Tags: php, yii2

I want to access session or `Yii::$app` in config file like ( `config/main.php` or `config/main-local.php`) !
Is that possible or not?
I want to check session and make some style available!

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'assetMap' => [
            'r.css' => Yii::$app->session['lang'] ? 'css/styleltr.css' : 'css/stylertl.css' ,
        ],
    ],
```

> or how do something like that in assetmanager????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access user session in your config file. But, you could use a conditional in your layout and register different assets based on session values.

Comment: It's probably also possible to do this in the asset bundle class.

Answer (score 0):

try accessing what you need this way

```
 \Yii::$app->getAssetManager()->assetMap;
```

Comment: get this error : Call to a member function getAssetManager()

Comment: Well the access to the assetMap is Right (i tested now) but for your the error is something related to your function or the to the content of session.

Comment: sorry but i have no access `Yii::$app->session` in config ? is that possible!

Comment: I think a good solution is eval the situation in controller and the use different layout or directly test in layout the lang and the load the css you need.